# Preposition "in" differences in usage

Tags: preposition

I was given the following two sentences to consider.

> 1. Dies ist eine der ersten Einrichtungen, in die Kinder kommen.
> 2. Kinder kommen nach dem Kindergarten in diese Schule.

The first sentence I managed to work out to say *This is one of the first facilities where children go.*

However, the use of the preposition **in** confused me.

In the second example, I managed to work it out as *Children go after Kindergarten to these schools.*

Why is the preposition **in** different for both examples

Comment: There is almost never a single 1-to-1 translation for any word in any language. Especially for such versatile words as prepositions. So the answer would be "because it's the way the German works".

Comment: What @Eller sais. And: A more literal translation could be "This is one of the first facilities in which children come". Not sure, whether this could be correct in english, though...

Comment: It isn't different. "...where children go" is simply an idiomatic alternative expression for the clumsier "...to which children go". So in this context, *in* + institution corresponds to "to", plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

> Kinder kommen nach dem Kindergarten **in diese Schule**.

This is a pretty straightforward use of a prepositional object giving a direction, as suggested (not strictly required) by the verb *kommen*. *Nach dem Kindergarten* in contary is an adverbial of time, because it's an addition not tightly connected to the verb *kommen* in particular.

---

> Dies ist eine der ersten Einrichtungen, **in die** Kinder kommen.

This is way trickier. The word *die* doesn't belong to *Kinder*, instead, it's a backreference to *Einrichtungen*. *Kinder* has no article here, it's 
"children as a kind". With article for *Kinder*:

> Dies ist eine der ersten Einrichtungen, **in die** die Kinder kommen.

You may replace the first *die* with the relative pronoun *welcher/welche/welches*:

> Dies ist eine der ersten Einrichtungen, **in welche** (die) Kinder kommen.

This construction *preposition+relative pronoun (or article as a relative pronoun)* to my knowledge is possible in English, too. But it seems to be bad style, English speakers seem to prefer a passive participle construction as this one:

*This is one of the first instititutions attended by children.*

While this is certainly possible in German, too,

> Dies ist eine der ersten von Kindern besuchten Einrichtungen.

it sounds pretty "technical" in German. People don't talk like that and only write like that if they want to sound distant. The natural way in German is the relative clause lead by a preposition+article as a relative pronoun.

Comment: In the sentence after *trickier* I would replace *article* by something more neutral (since it is a relative pronoun) to avoid confusion with the grammatical *article*.

Comment: I've edited my answer.