# "bei der" in "Vollzeit - Eine Arbeitsstelle, bei der man jeden Tag unter der Woche arbeitet"

Tags: grammar-identification

In the sentence

> Vollzeit - Eine Arbeitsstelle, bei der man jeden Tag unter der Woche arbeitet

I'm confused by the *bei der* part.

I know that *bei* has a whole host of meanings, but I know **bei der Arbeitet** would mean at work.

I just don't understand the use of bei and then the definite article in this context.

Why is bei being used in this context, and more importantly, why do I need the definite article "der" in this case?

Comment: "Bei" is e.g. used for: at, in, with, near, among

You could say "Ein Arbeitsplatz, der mir gefällt." "A workspace that I like."

This is a relative clause excluding leaving the whereabouts-part unknown, so you don't need "bei" which describes a positional relation.

Bei is used in kind of a relational context (physically and emotionally)

"Ich bin bei dir" -> "I am with you"
"Menschen bei denen man sich wohlfühlt" -> "People with whom you feel comfortable"
"He is no longer among/with us" -> "Er ist nicht mehr bei uns"

Answer (score 4):

You are mistaken.

> Bei der Arbeit — at work

Here, *Arbeit* is a noun, which can easily be seen because it's capitalized.

> …, bei der man arbeitet.

in contrary uses a finite verb form (3rd person singular) of the verb *arbeiten*.

This is a relative clause lead by *preposition+article as a relative pronoun*, as in your [previous question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48790/preposition-in-differences-in-usage). The meaning is *at which one works.*

You should revisit your exercises on relative clauses so you can spot this more easily. In German it's extremely common to use articles as relative pronouns. The "real" relative pronouns are rarely used. This is pretty similar to demonstrative pronouns, they are often replaced by the definite article as well.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, hmm, hmm ... Looking up *full time* in Langenscheid-Longman's *Dictionary of Contemporary English*, I read:

> **full time** [...] (in certain types of sport, esp. football) the end of the fixed period of time **during which** *(my emphasis)* a match
>   is played

Okay, this *full time* and your *Vollzeit* are not identical at all, that's true. But the grammatical structures of the explanations are. *... bei der* ... and *during which*.

Problem solved? ;-)